# Usage of "widening/growing" as related to availability

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, usage

Would **widening / growing** be sensible in this sentence to imply more people can afford to make movies?

*The availability of movie production _______ as cameras are getting cheaper*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like this I would go for the more quantitative ‘increasing’.

Also, the word ‘availability’ doesn’t seem quite right to me; I’d probably say it as:

> The accessibility of movie production is increasing as cameras are getting cheaper.

However, I’d be more likely to say it as:

> Movie production is becoming more accessible as cameras are getting cheaper.